# CSS - div not filling space between other two divs in chrome or ie

Tags: css, html

I have three divs that are supposed to sit next to each other. This works correctly in Firefox, but in IE and Chrome the middle div is not filling to the top of its container div. It fills correctly when there is nothing inside of it, but as soon as I add the buttons the div goes down the page some. I have set up and example here:

http://jsbin.com/ONuqUSom/1/edit

The middle div is the one with the id of 'transferButtons' if you comment out the buttons inside it you can see the placement that I would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add `vertical-align: top` to your `transferButtons` div.